# Removing visited style in href attribute

Tags: html

I would like to know if is it possible to change the visited style inline , not in the CSS, something similar to

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible, the only alternative would be using `<style>` tag:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <!-- Or you could use Javascript-->
  <a href="#" onmouseover = "this.style.textDecoration = 'none'">Link 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```